# Check if Table Databodyrange has value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like help in this section of my code where I want it to show a msgbox if the table already has data, but I am not able to set it. With my current code it shows the msg regardless of whether or not there is data in the table.

```
If Not ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Table has data", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`WorksheetFunction.CountA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta) to count the non-empty cells in the table body:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
   If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
       If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.DataBodyRange) > 0 Then
           MsgBox "Table has data", vbInformation
           Exit Sub
       End If
   End If
End With
```

Comment: Fyi Posted a relatively unknown alternative via analyze of a so called *xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value* :+) @BigBen

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *@BigBen* 's valid answer, I want to demonstrate a relatively unknown alternative via a so called `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet` Value, also referred to as ►`.Value(11)`.

The **`Range.Value(11)`** property returns all *values, formatting (styles), formulas, and names* of the specified Range object *(here: listobject)* in a simple **XML string** *(here: Spreadsheet format)* which is grouped into different xml node sections.

In this special case of a listobject's DataRange it suffices to check for the existance of a (first) "Row" node within the Worksheet's Table section via the `Instr` function alone *(thus avoiding more complicated XMLDom methods)*.

**Function HasData()**

```
Function HasData(lob As ListObject) As Boolean
'Purp:  check if data in listobject's DataBodyRange
'Meth:  by analyzing xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value string
    With lob
        If .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        If InStr(.DataBodyRange.Value(11), "<Row") Then HasData = True
    End With
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
    If HasData(Sheet1.ListObjects(1)) Then
        MsgBox "Table has Data."
    End If
```

**Help reference links**

- ([Excel XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)
- [Excel Range Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)